# POS/Receipt Printing from the browser (Citizen CT-S651)

Tags: css, web-applications, printing

I am trying to use a Citizen CT-S651 thermal printer to print HTML/CSS-Media formatted receipts from a web-browser.  We have been able to format the receipt correctly, but the trouble is after the receipt has been printed, the printer continues to spit out paper instead of cutting at the end of the content.  Chrome and Firefox's Print Preview window both show that the 'page' that will be printed is much longer than the content - I'm assuming 3276mm as that's the unchangeable 'length' of the paper size I'm using.

I've tried using css page-break-after, setting the height of the div explicitly, and @page rules but none of these seem to have an effect.

Perhaps using a different model of printer would work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a printer configuration side problem, search on your printer setup/configuration on the "control panel" something related to "cut" or "auto-cut" or "partial-cut". You can begin with rigth click over the printer icon and select "properties", search there. There is nothing to do in programing with this issue. The most of printers have this function.

Comment: Thanks, the setting was under Printing Preferences > Paper/Quality > Advanced.  Cutter Mode needed to be set to Full Cut/Full Cut

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this?

```
@media print {
   html, body {
       height: 99%;
   }
}
```